# Why does the first cache build show everytime i run `gatsby develop`

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

So i am using gatsby-cli and pulling data thru wordpress-graphql to gatsby. now the `gatsby develop` should pull the data and monitor the changes made and then pull in that specific data which is new but i am seeing the `first build time cache` every time i hit run the gatsby develop. it is a bit slow because i believe it pull all the data every time. help me out, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the detailed [docs (cache section)](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#develophardcachedata), there's a hardCacheData property that allows you to use cached data. By default, it's set to `false`.

> **develop.hardCacheData**
>
> This option is experimental. When set to true,
> WordPress data will be hard-cached outside the Gatsby cache in
> `./.wordpress-cache/caches`. This is useful for preventing the need to
> re-fetch all data when the Gatsby cache automatically clears. This
> hard cache will automatically clear itself when your remote WPGraphQL
> schema changes, or when you change your plugin options.
>
> When using this option, be sure to gitignore the wordpress-cache
> directory in the root of your project.

To enable it just:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
  options: {
    develop: {
      hardCacheData: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This option is (and has been) enabled on my site but I still get the warning on every build, so something else is at play.